# Compactness implies closedness in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: general-topology

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\cl}[1]{\overline{#1}}$
$\newcommand{\e}{\varepsilon}$
I am showing from first principles that compactness in $\mathbb R^n$ implies closed-ness. The definitions I have are the open cover one for compactness and "closed is complement of open" for closed sets.

The following is my proof. I would appreciate if anyone pointed out any errors, if any.

Let $x \in \R^n - E$. The collection $\{\R^n - \cl{B}(x,\e)\}_{\e > 0}$ is an open cover of $E$ (since the only point it does not contain is $x$). By compactness, there exist $\e_1 < \cdots < \e_n$ such that
$$\left(\R^n - \cl{B}(x,\e_1)\right) \cup \cdots \cup \left(\R^n - \cl{B}(x,\e_n)\right) \supset E.$$
Hence $\R^n - \cl{B}(x,\e_1) \supset E$, so $\cl{B}(x,\e_1) \subset \R^n - E$. In particular, $x$ is an interior point of $\R^n - E$, as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, any compact subset $K$ of a Hausdorff space is closed. Indeed, suppose that $x\notin K$. Since our space is Hausdorff, for each $k\in K$ there are *disjoint* open sets $V_k,U_k$ such that $k\in V_k,x\in U_k$. The open sets $V_k$ cover $K$. Since $K$ is compact, you can keep finitely many $V_1,\ldots,V_n$. Set $U= U_1\cap U_2\cap \cdots \cap U_n$. Then $U$ is an open set containing $x$ that doesn't meet $K$. In fact, we have proven something stronger: the open set $V=V_1\cup V_2\cup\cdots \cup V_n$ contains $K$ and is disjoint from the open set $U$ that contains the point $x$. That is, we have proven that in a Hausdorff space, disjoint *points* and *compact sets* may be separated by open sets.

Comment: (This is one of the results that support the idea that compact sets behave like points in Hausdorff spaces.)

Comment: Aha! I recall this result from Munkres and using it over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks great! I especially like that you've avoided an unnecessary argument via contradiction (not that I don't like those, but they often make a proof harder to understand).